# How do I add a \n to the end of the record on file using AWK

Tags: awk, echo

I have a file that can contain 1 or many lines

```
oracle1.txt
oracle2.txt
oracle3.txt
```

How do I using AWK put a \n after the last line only so it will show

```
oracle1.txt
oracle2.txt
oracle3.txt\n
```

I tried `echo -e "\n" >> manifest.txt` but I get a -e a the end of the file instead of the \n.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in awk use printf and something like: printf"\n"

Comment: `awk '1;END{print ""}'` but `echo '' >> manifest.txt` is enough

Comment: Why? Is your file missing a newline on the last line? I assume you want to add a newline instead of the characters ``\`` and `n`, but the question is not really clear. And why awk specifically?

Comment: `echo >> manifest.txt` (not from (t)csh where you need `echo "" >> manifest.txt`)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, `echo >> manifest.txt` will do the job in most shells, `echo '' >> manifest.txt` might be safer if you do not know the shell.

If you really want to do this in `awk` you could use an `END` rule (also mentioned in the comments): `awk 'END{printf "\n"}' >> manifest.txt`.

Instead of `printf`, you could use `print` & instead of `END` you could use `BEGIN`, too: `awk 'BEGIN{print ""}' >> manifest.txt`

If you want to use `manifest.txt` as an input to `awk` but not as output (`awk` cannot read & write the same file), a simple `awk 1 manifest.txt` will do (at least on `GNU awk`, if not `awk '1;END{print ""} manifest.txt` should do the trick). This is because the input is split into *records* by the *record separator* `RS` (defaulting to `\n`) , `1` will always evaluate to true, so the default *action* (`{print}`) will be performed for all lines. `print` is equivalent to `print $0` which in turn is the same as `printf $0 ORS`, `ORS` being the *output record separator* defaulting to `\n`.
So even if the last *record* does not end with `\n` in the input, it will be followed by `\n` in the output.